# Is there any reason to use this Regex method over String.IsNullOrEmpty()?

Tags: c#, string, asp.net-3.5

I have a method called isStringOnlyWhitespace():

```
public static bool isStringOnlyWhitespace(string toEval)
{
    string stringNoWhitespace = Regex.Replace(toEval, @"\s", "");
    if (stringNoWhitespace.Length > 0) return false;
    else return true;
}
```

Is there any reason to use this method to check for blank/null strings over String.IsNullOrEmpty()?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure, if you are shooting for slower code that is harder to read :)

You really want to use `string.IsNullOrWhitespace` though. Whoever wrote that code might have done so before this method existed. But even still, I'd prefer `myString.Trim().Length == 0` in that case.

Comment: `string.IsNullOrWhitespace` was introduced with .NET 4.0, so older versions can only use `string.IsNullOrEmpty`.

Comment: Thanks Oded, I forgot it's new. I edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: +1, minor gripe. I would much rather just hand code IsNullOrWhitespace than do an allocation.  The method is fairly straight forward to code up.

Comment: This would be the correct answer if I was using .net 4.0.  +1.

Answer (score 2):

The method you give doesn't handle nulls whereas `String.IsNullOrEmpty` does.

That would indicate to me that passing your method a null value is an error condition which is different behavior from `String.IsNullOrEmpty`.

Also, as others have pointed out, your method would return true for `isStringOnlyWhitespace("     ")` whereas `String.IsNullOrEmpty("    ")` would return false.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Strings containing only whitespace are not considered to be empty.  `isStringOnlyWhitespace(" ")` returns true, but `string.IsNullOrEmpty(" ")` returns false.

Answer (score 1):

No ;)

a) I think since .net 4 you can use string.IsNullOrWhitespace

b) try something like

```
public static bool IsStringOnlyWhitespace(this string str)
{
    // if you want to check for null:
    return str == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(str.Trim());
    // else
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(string.Trim());
}
```

Comment: you mean str.Trim()?  And even if you do, that doesn't handle nulls like IsNullOrEmpty

Comment: corrected the code, thanks for the hit.
The method I proposed either handles null or does not handle null, depending on the statement you pick.